# Connect to Azure cosmos db api for mongodb from an ssh tunnel

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, ssh-tunnel

I can connect to it from the nodejs driver with the following params:

```js
const params = [
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-40#retryable-writes
    'retryWrites=false',
    'readPreference=secondaryPreferred',
    `maxPoolSize=${1}`,
    'ssl=true',
].join('&')

const connectionUrl = `mongodb://${mongoUser}:${mongoPassword}@${mongoHost}:${mongoPort}?${params}`

console.log('trying to connect...')

const mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, {
    tlsInsecure: true, // The problematic param
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
})

console.log(
    'Successfully connected to mongodb database. Disconnecting client...'
)
```

The problem is that, some minutes after the connection, apparently all my queryies take forever to complete.

I think it's something with the `tlsInsecure` param, but I'm not exactly sure why this happens.

Is it possible to connect then to Azure cosmos db api for mongodb from an ssh tunnel?

I'd appreciate a guide or something. I followed [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/connect-mongodb-account) without success.

Comment: Cosmos DB is a service, and not something running on a vm you can access. You cannot install your own connection devices such as an ssh tunnel. That said: I'm not sure why you want to do this. Also, why are you adding a `tlsInsecure` setting?

Comment: Well, our cosmos db is hosted as a private network, so only vms in it can connect. The idea is that I could connect to our cosmosdb using a vm from the private network with an ssh tunnel, so that I don't have to install mongodb locally for testing. I could connect locally to cosmos db using the `tlsInsecure` param and an ssh tunnel, but after some minutes my queries just stop working, taking forever to respond.